# Laravel 5 - artisan seed [ReflectionException] Class SongsTableSeeder does not exist

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

When I run **php artisan db:seed** I am getting the following error:

```
[ReflectionException] Class SongsTableSeeder does not exist
```

What is going on?

My **DatabaseSeeder class:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        $this->call('SongsTableSeeder');
    }

}
```

My **SongsTableSeeder class:**

```
<?php

// Composer: "fzaninotto/faker": "v1.4.0"
use Faker\Factory as Faker;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use DB;

class SongsTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        $faker = Faker::create();
        $songs = [];
        foreach(range(1, 10) as $index)
        {
            $songs[] = ['title' => $faker->words(rand(1,4))];
        }

        DB::table('songs')->insert($songs);

    }

}
```

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: I thought **use Faker\Factory as Faker;** is doing the job?

Comment: What's the path to the file containing the `SongsTableSeeder` class definition?

Comment: Check [ReflectionException: Class ClassName does not exist - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475892/reflectionexception-class-classname-does-not-exist-laravel)

Comment: This is dump and bad

Answer (score 874, accepted):

You need to put `SongsTableSeeder` into file `SongsTableSeeder.php` in the same directory where you have your `DatabaseSeeder.php` file.

And you need to run in your console:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

to generate new class map and then run:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

I've just tested it. It is working without a problem in Laravel 5

Comment: I hadn't been 'use'ing the model in my seeder class. Works fine now.

Comment: `composer dumpautoload` also flies

Comment: composer dump-autoload solved the problem to me.
what composer dump-autoload really does?

Comment: @LuísAlmeida `dump-autoload` regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project, it's used when you have a new class inside your project. Normally running `make:*` will add the newly created class, but this won't occur if you manually create a seeder. At least that's how I understand it to work from 5 minutes of searching. I'm not an expert.

Comment: I tried this solution with Laravel 5.8 on a development server and `composer dump-autoload` worked for me.

Answer (score 25):

I solved it by doing this:

1. Copy the file content.
2. Remove file.
3. Run command: php artisan make:seeder .
4. Copy the file content back in this file.

This happened because I made a change in the filename. I don't know why it didn't work after the change.

Comment: Probably running composer dump-auto was easier. 

The autoloader is now looking for an older file. So if you dump this file via command line, it will generate a new autoloader file with the new file.

So in the future try this =)

Comment: For more information about composer autoloader see this site:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: van Asseldok, well, `composer dump-autoload` does not work for me. I must to recreate seeder class to make it working.

Comment: This helped me. ‘composer dump-autoload’ does not work for me as well, something to do with my server settings, or the fact that it’s a shared sever.

Answer (score 22):

File **SongsTableSeeder.php** should be in **database/seeds** directory or in its subdirectory.

You need to run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and then:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

or:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=SongsTableSeeder
```

Comment: able to see **Parse Error** with 'php artisan db:seed --class=SongsTableSeeder' command. thnks!!

Answer (score 18):

If you migrated to `Laravel 8`, you have to add a `namespace` to the `seeders` class:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

...
```

Next, in your `composer.json` file, remove `classmap` block from the `autoload` section and add the new namespaced class directory mappings:

```js
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeds/"
    }
},
```

An finally, do a `composer dump-autoload`.

For more information:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#seeder-factory-namespaces

Comment: Exactly what was missing! Thanks

Comment: This needs to be way more upvoted. Here, take my upvote and thanks.

Answer (score 9):

SongsTableSeeder.php should be in database/seeds directory

Console command steps:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and then:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

and then:

```
php artisan optimize
```

and then:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

or:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=SongsTableSeeder
```

Comment: Worked for me!

Especially the `php artisan optimize` part

Answer (score 4):

I'm running the very latest Laravel 5 dev release, and if you've changed the namespace you'll need to call your seed class like this:

```
$this->call('\todoparrot\TodolistTableSeeder');
```

Obviously you'll need to replace `todoparrot` with your designated namespace. Otherwise I receive the same error indicated in the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Do not forgot that the `composer dump-autoload` works in relation with the autoload 
 / classmap section of `composer.json`. Take care about that if you need to change seeders directory or use multiple directories to store seeders.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database/seeds",
      "database/factories"
    ],
},
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably specify the `.php` extension and It don't found your class.

What I was doing :

```
php artisan db:seed --class=RolesPermissionsTableSeeder.php
```

What solved my problem :
What I was doing :

```
php artisan db:seed --class=RolesPermissionsTableSeeder
```

Comment: thanks, it was so careless on .php for me

Answer (score 1):

When you migrate your project to `Laravel 8` and you get that error then you should follow some steps given below.

1.Go to your `composer.json` file.

2.Change autoload section

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
         "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
         "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
     }
 },
```

to

```
"autoload": {
     "psr-4": {
         "App\\": "app/"
      },
      "classmap": [
         "database/seeds",
         "database/factories"
      ]
},
```

3.Now run the command of `composer dump-autoload` or `composer update`

4.And last run command of `php artisan db:seed`

Answer (score 1):

Simply change:

`$this->call('SongsTableSeeder')`

to

`$this->call(SongsTableSeeder::class)`

Answer (score 0):

If our CustomTableSeeder is in same directory with DatabaseSeeder we should use like below:

```
$this->call('database\seeds\CustomTableSeeder');
```

in our DatabaseSeeder File;
then another error will be thrown that says: 'DB Class not found'
then we should add our DB facade to our CustomTableSeeder File like below:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I have used only SINGLE FILE with TWO classes in it following :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Lesson;

use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    //Lesson::truncate();

    Model::unguard();

    $this->call("LessonsTableSeeder");


}

}

class LessonsTableSeeder extends Seeder {

/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{

    $faker = Faker::create();

    foreach(range(1,30) as $index) {

        Lesson::create(['title' => $faker->sentence(5), 'body' => $faker->paragraph(4)]);

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have copied the seeders files from any other project then you need to run the artisan command `php artisan db:seed` otherwise it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

i got `[ReflectionException] Class Seeder does not exist` too and when i use `composer dump-autoload`, i got an error `preg_match(): JIT compilation failed: no more memory` when i run it.

What i did is that i change `;pcre.jit=1` to `pcre.jit=Off` in **php.ini**!
You can find the path by using `php --ini` in your terminal!

I am using mac with php 7.3! Hope that help any of you guys out there!

Answer (score -5):

I had the same "reflection exception" error. The solution was to copy the class file to the server, from dev, for me. dumb mistake, but given how many files we deal with its easy to forget to copy them over to the server every time.

Comment: This response is very vague and is coupled with your specific hosting setup.
Although your input is valued this may not help developers looking for solutions to this issue.

I think your issue is caused by you leaving it down to humans to copy files to the server.
It's encouraged to have a CI pipeline where files are automatically deployed to the server :)