# ReflectionException: Class ClassName does not exist - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

As soon, I am typing `php artisan db:seed` command.

I'm getting **Error** Like:

> [ReflectionException]
>       Class UserTableSeeder does not exist

`root@dd-desktop:/opt/lampp/htdocs/dd/laravel# php artisan db:seed`

Here, Is my `UserTableSeeder.php` & `DatabaseSeeder.php` Page

**UserTableSeeder.php**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder
{    
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->delete();
        User::create(array(
        'name'     => 'Chris Sevilleja',
        'username' => 'sevilayha',
        'email'    => 'chris@scotch.io',
        'password' => Hash::make('awesome'),
        ));
    }    
}
```

**DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Eloquent::unguard();
        $this->call('UserTableSeeder');
    }
}
```

I'm Referring This [Link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-and-easy-laravel-login-authentication) To Design & Develop Login Page.
Please Help me to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: which version of laravel are you using ?

Comment: Laravel 5.0 Mr @Aatif. Will It Matter For Running Any Artisan Command.

Comment: Let me try run it from my end. I will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - artisan seed \[ReflectionException\] Class SongsTableSeeder does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143315/laravel-5-artisan-seed-reflectionexception-class-songstableseeder-does-not-e)

Comment: My problem was that the class was used with a different casing than its definition, for example: myTestClass vs MyTestClass. I did not notice the problem until I was in production because I have a different filesystem locally than in production 

Comment: From my experience this is mostly due to an error in specifying the location or names of things. In my case it was a typo in the class name

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Perform a `composer update`, then `composer dump-autoload`.

*If the above doesn't solve the problem*, change the **`classmap`** in your *`composer.json`* file such that it contains the project-relative path to your php files:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php",
        "database/seeds/UserTableSeeder.php" //include the file with its path here
    ]
}, /** ... */
```

and soon after, perform a `composer dump-autoload`, and it should work now like a *breeze*!

#### Edit by @JMSamudio

If `composer dump-autoload` is not found, just enable this option `composer config -g -- disable-tls true`.

Comment: Hi Ahmad. 1) root@jbkinfotech-desktop:/# $php composer.phar update
2) root@jbkinfotech-desktop:/opt/lampp/htdocs/danish/laravel# $php composer.phar update 
Both giving composer.phar command not found. Sorry. I am very new to laravel. Don't Know Much Command. I Found Composer.json file. There I Edited. But, How To write command for dump-autoload command.

Comment: What happens if you type `composer` and press enter in the bash, in the _root_ of your project. i.e. for example your project is in `htdocs/danish/myProject`, execute it here.

Comment: root@danish-desktop:/opt/lampp/htdocs/danish/laravel# composer.
It display Usage, Available Commands

Comment: root@jbkinfotech-desktop:/opt/lampp/htdocs/danish/laravel# composer dump-autoload
It shows "Generating autoload files"

Comment: Now, php artisan db:seed shows new error
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Class 'User' not found

Comment: That means your `UserTableSeeder.php` is in fact loaded, check where you have used class `User`, refer to it with the correct namespace.

Comment: Hi Ahmad, I have no where declared class with class name 'User'. 
Error line showing in this line "User::create(array(" <<---- in UserTableSeeder.php. Sorry.

Comment: Bingo, I think the line should be `App\User` or `App\Models\User` if you have your `User` model in `Models` folder.

Comment: @AhmadBaktashHayeri can you explain what both commandos do exactly in light of the OP's question?

Answer (score 25):

From my experience, this will show up most of the time when the class you are trying to call has some bugs and cannot be compiled.  Check if the class that is not being reflected can be executed at its own.

Comment: This was it for me - tough one to track down!

Comment: if `composer dump-autoload` does not fix it, try this. In one case I had a wrong namespace

Answer (score 19):

A `composer dump-autoload` should fix it.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and I could solve it by doing `php artisan config:cache`.  The problem was that I had already run that command previously and later included some new seeder classes.  The cached configurations didn't recognize the new classes.  So running that command again worked.

If you see yourself making frequent changes to include new seeder classes then consider running `php artisan config:clear`.  This will enable you to make as many changes as you'd like and then after testing you can run `config:cache` again to make things run optimally again.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem with a `class`. I tried `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan config:clear` but it did not solve my problem.

Then I decided to read my code to find the problem and I found the problem. The problem in my case was a missing comma in my class. See my Model code:

```
{
    protected
    $fillable = ['agente_id', 'matter_id', 'amendment_id', 'tipo_id'];

    public
    $rules = [
        'agente_id' => 'required', // <= See the comma
        'tipo_id' => 'required'
    ];

    public
    $niceNames = [
        'agente_id' => 'Membro', // <= This comma is missing on my code
        'tipo_id' => 'Membro'
    ];
}
```

Comment: I can't believe how a little error like this can cause such a misleading error message, but yes, it happens. Thanks, you probably saved me a couple hours with this.

Comment: Me too. Looking at the code with scrutiny turned out the last single quote was missing 'tipo_id' => ```'required,``` instead of the correct ```'required',```. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 5):

**Check your capitalization!**

Your host system (Windows or Mac) is case insensitive by default, and Homestead inherits this behavior. Your production server on the other hand is case sensitive.

Whenever you get a **ClassNotFound** Exception check the following:

1. Spelling
2. Namespaces
3. Capitalization

Answer (score 4):

For some reason I had to run `composer dumpautoload -o`. Notice flag `-o` which mean with optimization. I don't have any idea why it works only with it but give it a try. Perhaps it helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

This will surely work. 
If not then, you need to do

```
composer update
```

and then, the aforementioned commands.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign it to a name space for it to be found.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is not resolved by `composer dump-autoload` or is not a newly created class.

Check for syntax errors in your class and its traits as well.
In my case, there was a syntax error in a Trait, but `ReflectionException` was shown for the actual Class using that Trait instead.

Answer (score 0):

When it is looking for the seeder class file, you can run **composer dump-autoload**. When you run it again and it's looking for the Model, you can reference it on the seeder file itself. Like so,

```
use App\{Model};
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use following command

```
php artisan db:seed --class=DatabaseSeeder
```

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly related to the question but received the error `ReflectionException: Class config does not exist`

I had added a new `.env` variable with spaces in it. Running `php artisan config:clear` told me that any `.env` variable with spaces in it should be surrounded by `"`s.

Did this and  my application stated working again, no need for config clear as still in development on Laravel Homestead (5.4)

Answer (score 0):

Don't take this as the answer for this question. If it helps others with the same bug but the answers mentioned here not works for them. I also tried all the solutions mentioned here. But my problem was with the ***namespace*** I used. The path was wrong.

The namespace I used is:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

But actually the controller reside inside a folder named '*FrontEnd*'

so the solution is change the *namespace* to:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recreated class, and it worked. Copy all file content, delete file, and run `php artisan make:seeder ModelTableSeeder`. Because `composer dump-autoload` didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to write `app` in `use` uppercase, so `App`. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Usually error message `ReflectionException: Class app does not exist` appears in larval test when you forget to close connection.

if you're using setUp or tearDown function in your test do not forget to close connection by calling `parent::setUp` and `parent::tearDown`

```
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of using **psr-0** , check the class name does not contain underscore .

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when trying to reach an endpoint in a custom route file, that had a namespace prepended in `RouteServiceProvider`

- The namespace in the class was correct.
- The file path of the class file was correct.
- The controller call from the routes file was correct (when not taking the prepended namespace from the `RouteServiceProvider` into account)
- The default `$router->group(['namespace' ...])` in the `RouteServiceProvider` was **incorrect**.

Updating the namespace in the `RouteServiceProvider` solved the issue, as the relative controller path specified in the routes file was now resolving correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Check file/folder permissions**

I struggled with this error today, and no amount of cache, config, autoload clears did anything to help. To add to the confusion, the error was thrown if initiated by a web request, but accessing the class in tinker worked fine.

After checking for typo's, syntax errors, and incorrect namespaces, I ended up discovering it was a file permission issue. The folder and file containing my class did not have appropriate permissions so it was throwing this error. The incorrect permission level I had was 771 (folder) and 660 (file), by changing it to 775 and 664 I was able to get it working.

My understanding of the different behaviors is that when running from the command line it was reading the file as my user (which had all the permissions it needed), but when initiated from the web it uses the "other" permission group which could do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

For new Laravel users it's a common mistake to forgot to add the name space:

*routes/web.php*

```
use App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController;
```

*app/Http/Controllers/CompanyController.php*

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

Using Laravel 9.

Answer (score -1):

```
composer dump-autoload
```

this will fix it

Answer (score -1):

```
composer update
```

Above command worked for me.

Whenever you make new migration in la-ravel you need to refresh `classmap` in `composer.json` file .