# Getting "class does not exist" in Laravel 5.x

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting the error: `Class App\Http\Controllers\TranslatorService does not exist` regardless of the namespace being set in the controller correctly and the file being in the correct location.

route.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'response-time'], function     () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
        Route::get('/', function () {
            App::abort(404);
        });

        Route::resource('accounts', 'AccountController');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'v2'], function () {
        Route::get('/', function () {
            App::abort(501, 'Feature not implemented');
        });
    });
});
```

`AccountController.php` under `app/ComdexxSolutions/Http/Controllers` is a standard skeleton controller.

`TranslationService.php` is under the same path as `AccountController` and looks like:

```
<?php

namespace ComdexxSolutions\Http\Controllers;

use InvalidArgumentException;
use RuntimeException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class TranslatorService
{
    /**
     * Returns a class name base on a resource mapping.
     * The mapping comes from a config file (api.php).
     *
     * Example: `users` should return `\App\Models\User`
     *
     * @param string $resource
     * @return string
    * @throws NotFoundHttpException
     */
    public function getClassFromResource($resource)
    {
        // This is the models namespace
        $modelsNamespace = Config::get('api.models_namespace',     Config::get('api.app_namespace'));

        // This array contains mapping between resources and Model classes
        $mapping = Config::get('api.mapping');

        if (!is_array($mapping)) {
            throw new RuntimeException('The config api.mapping needs to be an array.');     
         }

        if (!isset($mapping[$resource])) {
             throw new NotFoundHttpException;
         }

        return implode('\\', [$modelsNamespace, $mapping[$resource]]);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a command class name based on a resource mapping.
     *
     * Examples:
     *     - getCommandFromResource('users', 'show') returns     \App\Commands\UserCommand\ShowCommand
     *     - getCommandFromResource('users', 'index', 'groups') returns     \App\Commands\UserCommand\GroupIndexCommand
     *
     * @param string $resource
     * @param string $action
     * @param string|null $relation
     * @return string
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException
     */
     public function getCommandFromResource($resource, $action, $relation = null)
    {
        $namespace = Config::get('api.app_namespace');
        $mapping = Config::get('api.mapping');

        // If the mapping does not exist, we consider this as a 404 error
        if (!isset($mapping[$resource])) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The resource [' . $resource . '] is not mapped to any Model.');
        }

        $allowedActions = ['index', 'store', 'show', 'update', 'destroy'];

        if (!in_array($action, $allowedActions)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('[' . $action . '] is not a valid action.');
        } 

        // If we have a $relation parameter, then we generate a command based on it
        if ($relation) {
            if (!isset($mapping[$relation])) {
                throw new NotFoundHttpException('The resource [' . $resource . '] is not mapped to any Model.');
            }

            $command = implode('\\', [
                $namespace,
                'Commands',
                $mapping[$resource] . 'Command',
                ucfirst($mapping[$relation]) . ucfirst($action) . 'Command'
            ]);
        } else {
            $command = implode('\\', [
                $namespace,
                'Commands',
                $mapping[$resource] . 'Command',
                ucfirst($action) . 'Command'
             ]);
         }

        // If no custom command is found, then we use one of the default ones
        if (!class_exists($command)) {
             if ($relation) {
                 $command = implode('\\', [
                    'ComdexxSolutions',
                    'Console',
                    'Commands',
                    'DefaultCommand',
                    'Relation' . ucfirst($action) . 'Command'
                 ]);
             } else {
                 $command = implode('\\', [
                     'ComdexxSolutions',
                     'Console',
                     'Commands',
                     'DefaultCommand',
                     ucfirst($action) . 'Command'
                     ]);
                   }
                 }

        if (!class_exists($command)) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('There is no default command for this action and resource.');
        }

        return $command;
    }
}
```

Directory Structure:

http://laravel.io/bin/l59qa

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/comdexx-solutions-dcas$ tree -L 2 app
app
├── ComdexxSolutions
│   ├── Billing
│   ├── Console
│   ├── Contracts
│   ├── DbCustomer.php
│   ├── Events
│   ├── Exceptions
│   ├── Facades
│   ├── Http
│   ├── InvokeUser.php
│   ├── Jobs
│   ├── Listeners
│   ├── Models
│   ├── Providers
│   ├── Repositories
│   ├── Search
│   ├── Services
│   ├── spec
│   ├── Traits
│   ├── Transformers
│   └── Views
├── Console
│   ├── Commands
│   └── Kernel.php
├── Entities
├── Events
│   └── Event.php
├── Exceptions
│   └── Handler.php
├── Http
│   ├── Controllers
│   ├── Kernel.php
│   ├── Middleware
│   ├── Requests
│   └── routes.php
├── Jobs
│   └── Job.php
├── Listeners
├── Modules
├── Providers
│   ├── AppServiceProvider.php
│   ├── ErrorServiceProvider.php
│   ├── EventServiceProvider.php
│   └── RouteServiceProvider.php
├── Repositories
└── User.php

33 directories, 13 files
```

Comment: You can try this: `php artisan dump-autoload` or `composer dump-autoload`. If that doesn't work, maybe the class `TranslatorService` needs to extend  `controller`

Comment: You said your file is named TranslationService.php but your class is TranslatorService. Have you tried renaming your file to be the same name as the class?

Comment: Happens mostly when new classes don't get updated in composer.json I suppose. If you are sure that the namespaces used are correct, then check this answer [***HERE***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475892/reflectionexception-class-classname-does-not-exist-laravel/32476236#32476236).

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick follow up on this one - I helped this user on IRC and we ended up doing a webex. The root cause ended up being that a totally different file than what was posted above.

In **controller.php** there was a call to `TranslatorService`, but the correct namespace wasn't present for controller to find TranslatorService. Hence the error.

It was a little harder to find because the error didn't flag as coming from controller.php

The user who posted the question ended up doing a global search on TranslatorService across his project, and we looked at each file it was found in until we found the issue.

If you're reading this because you have a similar error, a few tips to remember are:

1. `class does not exist` - usually means you're trying to use something in your code that can't be found. It might be misspelled but more often than not, it's an issue with *namespaces*.
2. If you have this error - the technique of searching everything can be a great way to find where this is coming from if it's not immediately obvious.

Comment: His `ComdexxSolutions` is the  `app` folder i think