# defining route with new or existing class php artisan is giving error class not found. whether predefined routes for same controller is working fine

Tags: php, laravel, routes, classnotfoundexception, classnotfound

getting error when on adding new route from new or old controller. from php artisan route:list giving error

> ReflectionException class 'App\Http\Controller\Classname not exist
>   whether it exist and existing  routes with same class working
>   properly. running on xampp php 7.2

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('/selcetPlan','PlanStatusContoller@selectPlan');
```

**PlanStatusController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Plandetails;

class PlanStatusController extends Controller
{
    public function selectPlan(){
        $plande=Plandetails::all();
        return view('panel.planselect')->with('plan',$plande);
    }
}
```

'''

```
 php artisan route:list
```

**giving below error in cli**

```
ReflectionException  : Class App\Http\Controllers\PlanStatusContoller does not exist at C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:790
    786|         if ($concrete instanceof Closure) {
    787|             return $concrete($this, $this->getLastParameterOverride());}
    789|
  > 790|         $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
  Exception trace:
  1   ReflectionClass::__construct("App\Http\Controllers\PlanStatusContoller")
C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Containe
r\Container.php:790
  2 Illuminate\Container\Container::build("App\Http\Controllers\PlanStatusCont
oller") C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Containe
r\Container.php:667

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: Please add your routes file, and you controller code.

Comment: Have you checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475892/reflectionexception-class-classname-does-not-exist-laravel) answer, by chance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReflectionException: Class ClassName does not exist - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475892/reflectionexception-class-classname-does-not-exist-laravel)

Comment: @atymic route and controller code is attached . if i remove this route than every thing run perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes are :

1. Controller.php doesn't have a class that you defined in the web.php
2. Controller you defined is wrong

*If you can attach your error with code, its easy for us to give you an exact answer

Try add this code under the namespace in PlanStatusController.php:

```
Use App\Http\Controllers\Controller
```

Comment: code is attached please look into that and help me to resolve.

Comment: Add this under the to the namespace  : 

Use App\Http\Controllers\Controller

Comment: still same problem is there even after adding use App\Http\Controllers\Controller