# Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Point\RedeemRequestsBoController does not exist error

Tags: laravel

Use Laravel 5.6 and I want to create page booking room in my website management system.

Here's my code:

Route

```
Route::namespace('Point')->group(function () {
Route::get('/Admin/Point/redeem-requestsbo', 'RedeemRequestBoController@index');
// Crm Booking Room
        Route::delete('redeem-requestsbo/destroy', 'RedeemRequestsBoController@massDestroy')->name('redeem-requestsbo.massDestroy');
        Route::resource('redeem-requestsbo', 'RedeemRequestsBoController');
```

Controller

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Point;


use App\CrmCustomer;
use App\Models\Point\RedeemBo;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use App\Http\Requests\Point\StoreRedeemRequestBoRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\Point\UpdateRedeemRequestBoRequest;
use App\Models\Point\RoomType;
use App\Models\Point\SpecialRate;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class RedeemRequestBoController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('view redeem request'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

        $roles = auth()->user()->roles->pluck('title')->toArray();
        $admin = in_array('Admin', $roles);

        if(!$admin) {
          $rows = RedeemBo::whereHas('crmCustomer', function($query){
              $query->where('email', auth()->user()->email);
          })->get();
        } else {
          $rows = RedeemBo::all();
        }

        return view('admin.point.redeem-requestsbo.index', compact('rows'));
    }
```

But I got error

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Point\RedeemRequestsBoController does not exist error
```

[booking room page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDUS3.png)
[file folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6vDu.png)

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of your folder/file structure?

Comment: yes i have sir wait a moment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475892/reflectionexception-class-classname-does-not-exist-laravel Have you looked at this yet?

Comment: not yet sir i will check that

Comment: still problem sir, i use composer dump-autoload

Comment: When do you get this error?

Comment: Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Point\RedeemRequestsBoController does not exist

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your web.php?

Comment: ok sir wait a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RedeemRequestsBoController@massDestroy` does not exist because the Controller class name is `RedeemRequestBoController`. *RedeemRequest with the (s)*

Comment: thanks very much sir you are the bes mr Bello Muktar, can i ask something after this??

Comment: Sure you can, I'll be glad to help

Comment: i will be create crud image with button details but image not yet integration to id or room name, how can i do this to integration with one blade??

Comment: I didn't understand your question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59289192/image-not-integration-to-id-or-room-name-at-crud-laravel