# Laravel new controllers not working after deploy, how i Solve this?

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I have a Laravel project and it works good, but I decided to update it and add new features. Since I deployed the project if I try to add new controllers or do and php artisan route:list I always get a 500 error that my class its not found `ReflectionException::("Class "AyudaController" does not exist")`

This is my web.php

```
Route::get('ayuda', [AyudaController::class, 'show'])->name('ayuda');
```

And this is my AyudaController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;



class AyudaController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        return view('ayuda');
    }
}
```

And I have a view ayuda.blade.php

Comment: Did you import the class anywhere in your `web.php` through a `use`  statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReflectionException: Class ClassName does not exist - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475892/reflectionexception-class-classname-does-not-exist-laravel)

Comment: You should clear application cache first. Use `php artisan optimize:clear`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to web.php file:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AyudaController;
```

You must import this controller before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you must import the classes which you use. in your case you should import **AyudaController** controller in web.php.

Answer (score 0):

Clear app cache and routing, check that you don't have a typo or case issue with use, names and namespacing.  My guess your problem is route caching though.