# Laravel 5.1 ReflectionException Class does not exist

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

We are working in team on a laravel project and I've pulled in my teammates work and when I try to run

> "php artisan migrate:refresh --seed"

I get this weird error:

```
[ReflectionException] 
Class ColorsTableSeeder does not exist
```

The file ColorsTableSeeder does exist so I have no idea why I get this error
ColorsTableSeeder:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ColorsTableSeeder extends Seeder
  {
    public function run()
    {
      DB::table('colors')->delete();
      $colorPalette = array('#000000','#663300', '#424153', '#999999', '#996633'); 
      $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
      $projects = App\Project::all(); //10

      foreach ($projects as $project)
      {
        foreach (range(1, 3) as $index) 
        {
            $project_id = $project['id'];
            DB::table('colors')->insert([
            'project_id' => $project_id,
            'color' => $faker->unique()->randomElement($colorPalette),
            ]);
        }
      // Reset
      $faker->unique(true);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143315/laravel-5-artisan-seed-reflectionexception-class-songstableseeder-does-not-e/26144180#26144180 This should help you

Comment: Thanks alot guys! composer dump-autoload did the trick!

Comment: I got the same error when migrating from laravel 4.2 to 5.1, the error could be misleading see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34992628/403999

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by doing:

> composer dump-autoload