# Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, centos7, laravel-5

I am currently trying to clone an existing project of mine from github. After clone I run `composer install` during the process I receive the following error:

`Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist`

I am running Laravel 5.2 on Centos 7.

I have seen references to:

- Removing spaces within the `.env` file.
- Removing the vendor directory & re-installing
- Removing certain packages required in composer.json

I have:

- Replaced my `.env` with the `example.env` to avoid any custom config errors.
- I have removed & re-cloned the repo.
- I have used the default `composer.json` shipped with Laravel to see if that makes a difference.

None of the above have brought me any joy. I also have the same environment set up on another machine with the application working fine. The only difference here is the machine (working) wasn't cloned from git - it was the initial build environment.

The stack trace I am receiving:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in /var/www/html/Acme/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:736
    Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/html/Acme/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(736): ReflectionClass->__construct('log')
    #1 /var/www/html/Acme/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array)
    #2 /var/www/html/Acme/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(674): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array)
    #3 /var/www/html/Acme/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(845): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('log')
    #4 /var/www/html/Acme/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(800): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
    #5 /var/www/html/Acme/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(769): Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependenc in /var/www/html/Acme/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 736
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll be watching this answer too, since I've had a similar problem.  I'm on laravel 5.1.28 and recently did composer update for the first time in a little while, and since then I get that error for builds to production on heroku.  I've rolled back the composer.json change I'd made, but as suspected no change; it's something to do with allll the updates that got pulled into vendor :(

Comment: @DianeKaplan I've posted an answer for you to cast your eyes over. It helped me track down my error...

Comment: thanks, @jakehallas!  I'm using postgres- do you happen to know if there's a similar extension I would need, or is it specific enough that my problem is probably something else?  I'm a total newbie so issues like this are way out of my comfort zone :/

Comment: and restart your http server.

Comment: For me this usually happened when I forgot to add "Use Log;" at the top of a file where required files are included..and used in inside methods.

Comment: Thanks, I got the error fixed by adding quotation marks around the .env values that contains space.

Comment: As stupid as this should sound, this error was provoked by simply missing a comma separating the declaration of the values of an array in a config file. Put the comma in between the two values and error was gone... ! I'm using Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Okay, after many hours of digging, the solution for *my problem* has been found. The reason why I say my problem is because the `Exception` is very mis-leading.

`Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist`

This exception simply means Laravel tried to log an error but couldn't instantiate Laravel's `Log` class. This is not due to the Log class going walk-abouts or hiding. This is because Laravel is still going through its boot process & has yet to load the `Log` class.

So, this exception is thrown because an error occurred during the boot cycle of Laravel - when this error occurred it tried to throw an exception - but it can't throw an exception because the `Log` class is yet the be loaded. Hence the reason we get a `ReflectionException`

This **has occurred in all versions of Laravel** the only reason we have seen the exception thrown in laravel 5.1 <= is because previously Laravel silently discarded the problem & carried on through its boot process - basically, your app would still break however you would not receive the `Log class exception`.

In my particular case I didn't have the `php-mysql` extension installed causing Laravel to break during its boot process.

Ultimately, it is incredibly difficult to debug what you may have done wrong due to the error been very mis-leading.

I hope this helps someone!

**EDIT:** On how to debug this error and find out WHICH missing extension/component is actually causing the problem take a look at @Ben Johnson's answer.

Comment: Yeah, this is Laravel's silent behaviour... I had this problem and in my case I had to install php-mbstring and php-xml extensions. So basically if I see this error I check and install extensions which are required here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2 (Server Requirements) or others if they are required by packages.

Comment: How did you actually fix the problem?

Comment: I installed the missing php package `php-mysql`

Comment: 'php70w-mysql' was missing in my case. This exception is misleading indeed. Thanks

Comment: @jakehallas will u pls mention missing php package php-mysql and reference link or instruction

Comment: I'm trying solve this issue for hours and can't find out what the problem is. You didn't mentioned how did you knew that you had missed package, @AlexKalmikov too.

I've also tried to `var_dump()` some info from the lines that mentioned in the error, and nothing, just empty arrays...

Comment: @jakehallas and? Whats the solution?

Comment: With me happened the same thing, but in my case I forgot to update the namespace when moving a class to another folder.

Comment: This error occurs on artisan command whenever there is an exception loading the framework. In my case, a package was removed but one of its dependency was in use so i was getting the error

Answer (score 36):

In your .env file make sure you have no spaces for values

for example this is allowed

```
DB_USERNAME=homestead
```

this is not allowed

```
DB_USERNAME=home stead
```

you can wrap the value in quotes if you have spaces.

```
DB_USERNAME="home stead"
```

really wish they used json for the .env file, maybe we should request that feature

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Spaces may not have caused the issue for the question asker, but it definitely caused mine. This answer kept me from what would look to be a long drawn out goose chase.

Answer (score 36):

The underlying error is revealed by modifying `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php` and placing the following at the top:

```
<?php

namespace {
    use Monolog\Logger as Monolog;
    class log extends Illuminate\Log\Writer {
       function __construct()
       {
            $this->monolog = new Monolog("local");
       }
    }
}

//Add curly-braces around the original content, like so:

namespace Illuminate\Container {
    //All original code in this file goes here.

    //...
}
```

(Credit to https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/class-log-does-not-exist/replies/160902 for this idea.)

To add to the list of root-causes for this message, defining a closure in a configuration file *and* calling `php artisan config:cache` subsequently will cause this (at least in Laravel 5.1). Solution for this manifestation: don't define closures in Laravel configuration files, per https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9625 .

Comment: This reviewed the real exception being thrown - which was that I was trying to use a method that used a Facade in a config file(config/).

Comment: This helped, but didn't solve entire problem. I also got error that class config is missing, helped adding this after log class :
inline `class config extends \Illuminate\Log\Writer {
  function __construct()
  {
   $this->monolog = new Monolog("local");
  }

 public function get($test, $test2)
 {
   return $test;
  }
 }

}`

Comment: Add a line `        $this->monolog->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('/tmp/log.txt'));
` to actually write a log, which can reveal the cause

Comment: 'PHPExcel_Shared_Font' not found in app/config.php' was the real error for me had to delete the file and update composer. This piece of code showed the real error. Thanks

Comment: Awesome! This workaround really saved my day :) Turned out someone decided to ignore composer.lock so local dev and our build servers got out of sync and packages ended up not being installed.

Answer (score 15):

Remove file `bootstrap/cache/config.php` . This file may not be displayed on windows, if so, use double commander for example. Definitelly will work!

EDIT:

It may be caused by caching .env file, if it's your case, try to remove 
`bootstrap/cache/config.php`

Answer (score 5):

I was noticing the same behavior after adding a few lines to my .env files. Spaces are not allowed without quotes, and so this can be fixed like:

`APP_YOUR_NAME="A value with some spaces"`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the missing of PDO extension was the problem. After installing it, the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT::**

Because I wasn't satisfied with the rather clumsy debugging and reworking paths, etc to get the VM running smoothly, I reflected on the process and reinstalled the vagrant box laravel/homestead (`virtualbox 1.0.1`)

*For me* the issue potentially stemmed from a missing comma in `config/app.php`. The missing comma likely halted the compilation process and spit out the `Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist` error.

---

This is not a direct answer, but serves more as a guide post to those who venture into this abyss of silent errors

System: macOS Sierra

Vagrant: `1.9.1` (Latest Version at time of writing)

VM: laravel/homestead (`virtualbox 0.4.0`)

Laravel Version: `5.1.*`

PHP: `7.0.*`

---

After repeated attempts to resolve the issue which include:

1. rewriting, removing .env for potential parse issues
2. php7.1 and the mcrypt / mbstring issues
3. installing composer suggested packages
4. updating homestead.rb
5. PATH related issues

Critically, (for me) it seemed it was the virtualbox version in the initial set up:

`vagrant box add laravel/homestead`

Instead try supplying the version number like so:

`vagrant box add laravel/homestead` **`--box-version 0.4.0`**

---

**misc**:

I have attempted and failed with the following `laravel/homestead` virtualbox versions:

- `1.0.1` (default)

and `laravel/homestead-7`:

- `0.2.1`

Answer (score 3):

Also this is due to a **syntax error** in some file in the **conf/ directory** or **.env  file**.
In my case I got this error because I forget to put `::class` at the end of the line when adding a service provider and facade, to the array providers and alises in conf/app.php file. I corrected this and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

When composer updating, i think laravel makes some validations.

- Install "unzip" package("sudo apt install unzip") if not installed.
- Check all required extensions such as "mysql", "json", "curl", "xml", "zip", etc. and install("sudo apt install php7.1-mysql") if not installed.
- Check your file/folder permissions.
- Check your ".env" file.
- Check your "config" files.
- Run "composer update" again.

Installing unzip works for me. Good Luck :)

Comment: `apt` is not part of Centos, you would be looking at adding the relevant repositories and using `yum` instead.

Comment: yeah, my mistake, @moopet is right. my explanation is for ubuntu. other distributions like centos you should use like this: "yum install php-mysql".

Answer (score 2):

I was typing a CMD in the CLI and accidentally typed it in the app config file. I had to follow this procedure in order to find the problem.

Solution, how to find problem:

- make a backup copy of config folder. try to delete one config at a
- time and try to run composer/artisan command that failed. When you
- find file that failed - search for a row that can possibly fail.
- Reason why it is failed is: You use class constant that is not loaded
- yet. You use class/function that is not loaded yet. etc

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/class-log-does-not-exist?page=2

Answer (score 2):

This problem is usually caused by spaces between words in the .env file.
Make sure if you have something like

```
SITE_DESCRIPTION = Social Network for dogs
```

you replace it with

```
SITE_DESCRIPTION = 'Social Network for dogs'
```

Answer (score 2):

This error may be caused by an error in one of the config files.
To locate which file is causing it, change the function loadConfigurationFiles in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php to:

```
protected function loadConfigurationFiles(Application $app, RepositoryContract $repository)
{
    foreach ($this->getConfigurationFiles($app) as $key => $path) {
        var_dump('loading key: ' . $key . ' -- path: ' . $path);
        $repository->set($key, require $path);
    }
}
```

Run php artisan and the last loading "key" is the config file causing the error.
Correct it and don't forget to remove the your var_dump command...
Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and none of the solutions here worked out

I've found that there's an exception of permission denied to `config` folder

After fixing the permission everything worked!

---

**How to figure it?**

Put a break-point in 
`vendor/laravel/framework/src/illluminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php`

line 101 inside the catch of the handle function.

This is how I've found out about the permission denied.

Answer (score 1):

```
Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist
```

This Error Comes laravel 5.2 & > versions:

**My mistakes are:**

**Tips1:**
when You missing (;) end of your code in config File

Other syntax Error This error comes.

My Error code:

```
<?php
return [
'data' => [
    'common' => [
        'AuthKey1' =>  "17086...........9a87a1",
        'AuthKey2' =>  "17086...........9a87a1",
        'AuthKey3'   =>  "17043...........59969531",
    ],
]
]
```

Correct code: **Missing (;) End of return Array**

```
<?php
return [
'data' => [
    'common' => [
        'AuthKey1' =>  "17086...........9a87a1",
        'AuthKey2' =>  "17086...........9a87a1",
        'AuthKey3'   =>  "17043...........59969531",
    ],
]
];
```

Comment: or in my case, it was just a comma in between the array values ! Double check all your config files with a php syntax checker before scratching your head in despair !

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue after removing space in the **.env fil**e (*view .env in sublime because vi editor doesn't show space at end of the .env file.*) and run below commands.

Commands:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
php artisan clear-compiled
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after many hours of digging, the solution for my problem has been found. The reason why I say my problem is because the Exception is very mis-leading.

```
Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist
```

This exception simply means Laravel tried to log an error but couldn't instantiate Laravel's Log class. This is not due to the Log class going walk-abouts or hiding. This is because Laravel is still going through its boot process & has yet to load the Log class.

So, this exception is thrown because an error occurred during the boot cycle of Laravel - when this error occurred it tried to throw an exception - but it can't throw an exception because the Log class is yet the be loaded. Hence the reason we get a ReflectionException

This has occurred in all versions of Laravel the only reason we have seen the exception thrown in laravel 5.1 <= is because previously Laravel silently discarded the problem & carried on through its boot process - basically, your app would still break however you would not receive the Log class exception.

In my particular case I didn't have the php-mysql extension installed causing Laravel to break during its boot process.

Ultimately, it is incredibly difficult to debug what you may have done wrong due to the error been very mis-leading.

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had used the `route()` method in a config file. Obviously, this method does not work because these files don't use the Illuminate Helper, they are simple .php with data.

The configuration files are read before instantiating the Log class, which causes the error that [Jakehallas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34992628/2520761) explains very well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as said by @jakehallas . Its not related to what is showing in exception.

Actually if there is any dababase issue or other config varilables issue causes this.

Actually when i tried to change something in database.php i just duplicated same file as database-copy.php. I didn't execpt this causes issue.

After gone through what i have done before i just removed this database-copy.php file its working fine..

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of solutions provided here and elsewhere. It did not work for me. I solved it by manually removing /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php and updating the autoload files:

```
rm /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of error when you missed any of the dependencies of your project. 
 Run`php composer.phar update`

Answer (score 0):

Run `php artisan config:cache` solved it for me.

Or if you are on shared hosting without access to the Terminal/CMD, add this to your `Routs.php` file:

```
Route::get('/config-cache', function() {
    Artisan::call('config:cache');
    return '<h1>Config cache cleared successfully</h1>';
});
```

Then go to `yourdomain.com/config-cache` to run this script.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has mentioned orchestra/testbench yet I thought I'd just add the solution to my problem.

I was writing a Laravel package when I got this error in one of my unit tests. I was using `orchestra/testbench` to enable testing of Laravel-specific parts of the code.

The problem was simply that the test class was extending `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` instead of `Orchestra\Testbench\TestCase`.

Answer (score 0):

I had some negative value like

```
BUSINESS_RECONCILIATION_DAYS=-8
```

I needed to wrap

```
BUSINESS_RECONCILIATION_DAYS="-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a comma is missing in my config file (config/app.php) after I merged my branch to master.

[image: my code snippet]

it was a syntax error, but didn't display it.

Answer (score 0):

As previous answers has outlined we had an issue with one of our configuration files in laravel. We used the global $app variable which were no longer possible in laravel 5.2+.

The way we found this was to check which file failed to load in the loadConfigurationFiles method in src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php.

Answer (score 0):

Even this is an old thread, hope my answer could help someone someday (like me).
In my case,I found that I should run the artisan from the  terminal like so:

```
sudo php artisan command
```

That was craching cause it hasn't the permission to write to the log file.

Answer (score 0):

This also had me entertained for a few hours while trying to dockerize some outdated laravel apps for archiving. As has been already pointed out, the exception is thrown very early in the boot up of laravel.
In my case I created a git repo which contains the vendor directory (Because I'm archiving an old unmaintained app) and I accidentally added the line "config" instead of "/config" to .gitignore, so that several config folders inside vendor/symfony got lost in the process, leading to that exception.

Answer (score -2):

Just running

```
composer update
```

fixed the issue.