# Class 'User' not found laravel 5.2 right after fresh installation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have just installed fresh laravel 5.2 application following the guide in the documentation - https://laravel.com/docs/5.2#installing-laravel.

It's not first time I did that, but I didn't have such a problem before. 
I am getting this error:

FatalThrowableError in routes.php line 15:
Fatal error: Class 'User' not found

I my routes.php I have only:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome'); });
```

I can't understand where the problem can be. I have this error on fresh installation, never faced with such problem before. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a full screenshot with error:
[Screenshot with error](http://prntscr.com/atqix4)

List of errors:

```
FatalThrowableError in routes.php line 15:
Fatal error: Class 'User' not found
in routes.php line 15
at RouteServiceProvider->{closure}()
at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array()) in Route.php line 158
at Route->runCallable(object(Request)) in Route.php line 137
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Full routes.php file:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Comment: Please post code where you're trying to use `User` model

Comment: I am not trying to use in anywhere, this is the poin. I have just installed a new project.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: No, i don't know how to use it

Comment: In your .env set APP_DEBUG=true. Then hit the index page and post what errors you see.

Comment: I see this error - http://prnt.sc/atqix4

Comment: Can you post your full routes.php please?

Comment: Added full routes.php file to question

Comment: As I told, I have only done a basic instalation via composer, without editing something. A I get this error.

Comment: Try clearing your route cache: `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Sometimes the classes should be recompiled. Try `php artisan clear-compiled` and then `php artisan optmize`

Comment: This might be the issue introduced in 5.2. Check you have all your dependencies met as per https://laravel.com/docs/5.2#server-requirements

This never used to happen before 5.2 as Laravel 5.1 and below silently discarded errors of this type. The actual exception is extremely misleading.

See this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978828/uncaught-reflectionexception-class-log-does-not-exist-laravel-5-2/34992628#34992628

Answer (score 1):

```
php artisan clear-compiled  
php artisan optmize
```

That helped me! Thanks to everybody!