# ReflectionException: Class db does not exist

Tags: laravel

I am creating a library that uses `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB` to reference the database. I'm getting the following exception on the call to `DB::table()->where()->get()`: "ReflectionException: Class db does not exist." What is the problem and what do I need to do to overcome it?

I know that there is a process using `\Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager` to establish a connection to the database. But I haven't found any example on how to make this work with `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB`.

Code sample:

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

abstract class Data
{
    public static function tables($prefix, $mode=null)
    {
        $outbound = array();
        $tables = DB::table('information_schema.tables')->where('TABLE_NAME', 'LIKE', $prefix.'_%')->get();
        foreach ($tables as $table) {
            ...
        }
        return $outbound;
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
~/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:749
~/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:644
~/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:709
~/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1203
~/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:175
~/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:144
~/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:231
~/Data.php:XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a facade, add this to the top of the class to make it work:

```
use DB;
```

Or use full namespace:

```
$tables = \DB::table...
```

Comment: In addition to `use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` which is already in the code?

Comment: @JayBienvenu no, you can remove this line.

Comment: Took out the original `use` statement and replaced `DB` with `\DB`. Getting class 'DB' not found (no surprise).

Answer (score 0):

this is not correct way but you can write this way. give a '/' before DB

$tables = \DB::table('information_schema.tables')->where('TABLE_NAME', 'LIKE', $prefix.'_%')->get()

Comment: '/' before class name throws syntax error, did you mean '\'?

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR:

Temporarily commenting out lines with `DB::` and adding https://stackoverflow.com/a/39354471/729077 should help you figure out the real reason.

#### Longer explanation:

One of the reasons could be similar to those listed in this thread: [Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978828/uncaught-reflectionexception-class-log-does-not-exist-laravel-5-2), the only difference being `db` instead of `log` class that's missing.

It seems to depend on which class occurrence happens first in code - in yours and mine it was `DB`, while usually it is `Log` facade that triggers the error.

For me, the reason was missing 3rd party package, with its service provider added already to list in `config/app.php`. In result, every artisan command spat `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::connection()` error. After adding explicit `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB` to top of offending file, the error changed to yours (`class db does not exist`).

I've added code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39354471/729077, then commented out the line with `DB::connection()` and artisan has shown the real culprit. After `composer require`ing missing package, laravel started working again.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is getting this when running phpunit tests, I was able to fix it by extending `Tests\TestCase` instead of `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`