# Error "Class log does not exist" in laravel with composer

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to run commands composer update & php artisan serve i got these errors:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in /var/www/html/***/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:734
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/***/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(734): ReflectionClass->__construct('log')
#1 /var/www/html/***/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(629): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/***/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(697): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/***/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(849): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('log')
#4 /var/www/html/***/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(804): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#5 /var/www/html/***/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/C in /var/www/html/***/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 734
```

I already checked some solutions i red like spaces in .env but the problem still exists

Comment: I got the same error when migrating from laravel 4.2 to 5.1, the error is misleading see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34992628/403999

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug that was fixed in laravel 5.4. Please upgrade your laravel version.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6607

Answer (score 0):

you just need to delete the vendor folder and then try composer install command.
or
have you tried composer dump-autoload??

won’t download a thing. It just regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project (autoload_classmap.php). Ideal for when you have a new class inside your project.
Ideally, you execute composer dump-autoload -o , for a faster load of your webpages. The only reason it is not default, is because it takes a bit longer to generate (but is only slightly noticable)

Comment: Already did this, delete a vendor folder then run:
composer dump-autoload -o
composer install
but still getting the same error

Comment: which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel version is: 5.2