# Configuring the Laravel timezone base on the system timezone in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, centos, timezone

I'm trying  to set the timezone configuration on `config/app.php` base on my the system time on CentOS VM automatically.

```
'timezone' => 'America/New_York',
```

I've tried added these few lines of code on top of `config/app.php`

```
// Try #1
// $timeZone = shell_exec("date +\"%Z %z\" | awk '{print $1}'");
// dd($timeZone);  I got "EST\n"

// Try #2
// session_start();
// $timezone = $_SESSION['time'];
// dd($timeZone);

// Try #3
// $timezone = date_default_timezone_get()
// dd($timeZone);
```

None of these above seem to work.

How would one go about debugging this further?

Comment: How about using [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters) ? Something like that `Carbon::createFromTimestamp(0, 'America/New_York')->getTimezone();`

Comment: I tried this(https://i.imgur.com/ForViQq.png) I got : https://i.imgur.com/ramGmWS.png

Comment: Check this link for more info on the error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978828/uncaught-reflectionexception-class-log-does-not-exist-laravel-5-2 - make sure you add this `use Carbon\Carbon;` to your file as well

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$tz = $now->getTimezone();
$tz = $tz->getName();
```

If the above doesn't work I suggest you to look at [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters);

Your `config/app.php` file will be something like:

```
<?php
# include Carbon
use Carbon\Carbon;

return [
    . 
    .
    . 
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => Carbon::createFromTimestamp(0, 'America/New_York')->timezone->getName(),
    .
    . 
    .

];
```

---

To test the output of the above do not die dump `dd()` inside your `app/config.php` you can make a new route:

```
Route::get('/test-timezone', function() {
    dd(\Config::get('app.timezone'));
});
```

Make sure to clear the cache to see the changes: `php artisan config:cache`