# Laravel 5.7 upgrade, Uncaught ReflectionException: Class cache does not exist Container.php:779

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

When upgrading Laravel 5.5 to 5.7 and running composer install I see this error.
Has any one else experienced something similar?

I also upgraded php from 7.1 to 7.2 at the same time using forge, after reverting the code to laravel 5.5 staying with php 7.2 was not an issue.

Comment: **Related(?):** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978828/uncaught-reflectionexception-class-log-does-not-exist-laravel-5-2

Answer (score 1):

There were changes from Laravel 5.6 to 5.7 that might have caused this:

From the [Upgrade Notes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade):

> A new data directory has been added to storage/framework/cache. You should create this directory in your own application:
>
> ```
> mkdir -p storage/framework/cache/data
> ```
>
> Then, add a .gitignore file to the newly created data directory:
>
> ```
> cp storage/framework/cache/.gitignore storage/framework/cache/data/.gitignore
> ```
>
> Finally, ensure that the storage/framework/cache/.gitignore file is updated as follows:
>
> ```
> *
> !data/
> !.gitignore
> ```

There was also a change from Laravel 5.5 to 5.6, but from what it looks like this seems unlikely to be the cause.