# how to downgrade php7 to php5 fedora

Tags: php, laravel

php artisan serve not working regularly

am working on a project that was devloped in php 5   and fedora uses 7.2

and all repos for php5 on fedora return 404

```
php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in /home/ahmed/Documents/svn/osmall/trunk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:741
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ahmed/Documents/svn/osmall/trunk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(741): ReflectionClass->__construct('log')
#1 /home/ahmed/Documents/svn/osmall/trunk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array)
#2 /home/ahmed/Documents/svn/osmall/trunk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(674): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array)
#3 /home/ahmed/Documents/svn/osmall/trunk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(842): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('log')
#4 /home/ahmed/Documents/svn/osmall/trunk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(805): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#5 /home/ahmed/Document in /home/ahmed/Documents/svn/osmall/trunk/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 741
```

i tried: 
1-the .evn search for errors
2-i tried the composer clear cash and other stuff 
3- i searched for a timestamp   that might cause  issue 
4- i tried ...
5- am exhausted ..help

Comment: What is your actual question? Are you trying to downgrade PHP? If so, why? Also, recent versions of Laravel *require* PHP 7 (for good reason, since all 5.x versions have reached end-of-life).

Comment: It usually only takes an hour or two to convert old code to new. Well spent time in my opinion

Comment: This is not about programming but system administration, rather a question for https://superuser.com/  or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ Or edit the question to "How to upgrade code from PHP5 to PHP7

Comment: so it's all  about spending more time in upgrading this app code from php5 to php7

Comment: All versions below 7.1 are unsupported. It's a potential security risk not to upgrade.

Comment: You might just be missing some required extensions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978828/uncaught-reflectionexception-class-log-does-not-exist-laravel-5-2 Try listing `php -m` on terminal console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really require a php version that old and still want to use an up to date os version (which you should!!)

you can try docker:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.5"

services:
   php: 
       image: php:5.6-apache
       ports:
          - 80:80
       volumes:
          - ./:/var/www/html
```

-> this will limit your one application to use that old php version

Comment: good idea  now i have to google   ( how to use laravel with docker  )