# Laravel: Way to diagnose "uncaught reflection: class log does not exist" without guessing?

Tags: laravel

As we all painfully know, this message is generated when an error occurs before Laravel has had a chance to instantiate a "Log" class instance to handle it.  *And...* it therefore seems to completely conceal just what the underlying error is!

In my case the `php artisan` command won't run either.

Is there any way to find out what's wrong without "blind guessing?"

Comment: most (if not all) artisan commands have a `-v` option for verbose which will produce a stack trace.

Comment: Unfortunately, say `php artisan config:cache` *does* produce a stack trace, but that trace is not helpful.  It lists six entries, all within `Container.php` or `Application.php,` all apparently having to do with constructing the 'log' ReflectionClass.  The `-v` option does not produce anything more.  And, it doesn't tell me what *underlying* error caused Laravel to want to create a logger.

Comment: try `cache:clear` and `config:clear`.  next i'd try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I tried all of these things.  *Every* `php artisan` command fails.  `composer dump-autoload` runs but does not affect the problem.  I simply need to find a way to discover what the *underlying* exception was, that Laravel was trying to log.

Comment: In my case, the fact that the error "recently began to occur" led me to use `git diff --name-only` to find out which files had changed.  Sure enough, there was a *syntax error,* and that's what caused it.  But, really, should there not be a way to find out directly what the underlying error was?!  Really??!

Comment: Take a look here and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978828/uncaught-reflectionexception-class-log-does-not-exist-laravel-5-2

Answer (score 0):

When you want to handle exceptions, a good way to catch it would be to implement a way to trapping exception out of controllers or services. You can do it in the "render" method of the App\Exceptions\Handler class. In this "render" method, you can write a block of "if" code to show the messages generated by an exception when Laravel throws an exception. For example:

```
 public function render($request, Exception $exception)
 {
     if($exception) {
         // do something
         return response()->json(['error' => $exception->getMessage(), 
                 $exception->getTraceAsString()], 500);
     }

     // Or if you created an exception specialization
     if ($exception instanceof MyCustomException) {
         return response()->view('errors.custom', [], 500);
     }

     return parent::render($request, $exception);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This was indeed caused by a *syntax error,* and I'm really surprised that Laravel had even managed to "get started" by that point in time.  I literally found it by looking with `git` at a list of files that had recently changed.