# Class PermissionTableSeeder does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

i have an error. when i run `php artisan db:seed --class=PermissionTableSeeder`

appeared this error

> C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:809
> ReflectionException::("Class PermissionTableSeeder does not exist")

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
// 

// 

class PermissionTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $permissions = [
            'role-list',
            'role-create',
            'role-edit',
            'role-delete',
        ];

        foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
            Permission::create(['name' => $permission]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64516280/11199696). It will probably solve your problem.

Comment: Did you try to include the namespace `Database\Seeders\PermissionTableSeeder` ? You can also call the seeder to the `DatabaseSeeder` class using `$this->call(PermissionTableSeeder::class)` so that you don't need to add the class when seeding database

Comment: where can i use $this->call(PermissionTableSeeder::class)

Comment: @bariskau not work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so when you create a new class in the seeder, it is not autoloaded by the composer.
Just clear the cache, i.e call

> php artisan optimize:clear

and run the following command

> composer dump-autoload

and now run your seeder command.